# How's this for an SSR LTspice model?

Tags: ltspice, solid-state-relay, modeling

I probably need to use an SSR for a design. I have never used SSRs, I just know things that have read on data sheets and the internet. I am planning on using the following spice circuit for a model...

Instead of using an Roff resistance i have 1uA of leakage going in which ever direction has the lowest potential. Also I have 5mA input current required to turn on the switch.

Do you think this a good approximation of an SSR?

[image]

Comment: I guess it's a model of an SSR but it doesn't look like any real SSR that I have run across. If it's supposed to be a PV-actuated MOSFET type, it will be off by maybe 5 or 6 orders of magnitude in turn-on time, and the input characteristics also look dubious.

Comment: I can adjust the turn on/off time. Yes the input is wonky. It just there to assure there is at least 5mA of current potential at the input for the switch to turn. What I really care about is simulating the worst case leakage scenario.